# I use inner join but records are duplicating though I use "Distinct" and "Group By" in SQL Server 2008 R2 why?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

This is the query when I run this it gives me duplicate records but I remove the `INNER JOIN planingOrderBookHeader PLOH ON sd.StyleID=PLOH.StyleID` and the column `PLOH.OderBookID`, it gives records without duplicating but I need records with column name `PLOH.OderBookID` how can I solve this problem ?

```
SELECT 
       CPO.ID   
      ,CPO.StyleID 
      ,cpo.CustomerPo
      ,PLOH.OderBookID
      ,cpo.Process
      ,CPD.Qty
      ,cpd.RefID
      ,cpd.Uom
      ,UM.MeshType
      ,PRC.Name
      ,STC.NewStyleno
      ,SD.TypeID
      ,itm.Name Part
      ,SD.ColorID
      ,COL.Name Color   
      ,SD.FabricID
      ,FAB.Name Faric
      ,SHD.ItemID
      ,ITD.Name Item
      ,SHD.Image
FROM CustomerPO_Header CPO
   INNER JOIN styleconfirmHeader STC ON STC.StyleID=CPO.StyleID 
   INNER JOIN CustomerPo_Details CPD  ON CPO.ID=CPD.CusPOHeaderID   
   INNER JOIN StyleHeader SHD ON SHD.StyleID=CPO.StyleID
    INNER JOIN StyleDetails SD ON CPO.StyleID=SD.StyleID
    INNER JOIN ItemDetails itm ON SD.TypeID=itm.ID
    INNER JOIN ColorDetails COL ON SD.ColorID=COL.ID
    INNER JOIN ItemFabricDetails FAB ON FAB.ID=SD.FabricID
    INNER JOIN UOM UM ON Um.ID=CPD.Uom
    INNER JOIN ItemTypeDetails ITD ON SHD.ItemID=ITD.ID
    INNER JOIN process PRC ON PRC.ID=CPO.Process
   INNER JOIN planingOrderBookHeader PLOH ON sd.StyleID=PLOH.StyleID
```

Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test without knowing what data you have. However you could try moving the table that is causing your duplicates into a subquery instead of a join. so something like:

```
SELECT 
   CPO.ID   
  ,CPO.StyleID 
  ,cpo.CustomerPo
  ,(SELECT PLOH.OderBookID FROM planingOrderBookHeader PLOH WHERE sd.StyleID=PLOH.StyleID) AS OderBookID
  ,cpo.Process
  ,CPD.Qty
  ,cpd.RefID
  ,cpd.Uom
  ,UM.MeshType
  ,PRC.Name
  ,STC.NewStyleno
  ,SD.TypeID
  ,itm.Name Part
  ,SD.ColorID
  ,COL.Name Color   
  ,SD.FabricID
  ,FAB.Name Faric
  ,SHD.ItemID
  ,ITD.Name Item
  ,SHD.Image
FROM CustomerPO_Header CPO
INNER JOIN styleconfirmHeader STC ON STC.StyleID=CPO.StyleID 
INNER JOIN CustomerPo_Details CPD  ON CPO.ID=CPD.CusPOHeaderID   
INNER JOIN StyleHeader SHD ON SHD.StyleID=CPO.StyleID
INNER JOIN StyleDetails SD ON CPO.StyleID=SD.StyleID
INNER JOIN ItemDetails itm ON SD.TypeID=itm.ID
INNER JOIN ColorDetails COL ON SD.ColorID=COL.ID
INNER JOIN ItemFabricDetails FAB ON FAB.ID=SD.FabricID
INNER JOIN UOM UM ON Um.ID=CPD.Uom
INNER JOIN ItemTypeDetails ITD ON SHD.ItemID=ITD.ID
INNER JOIN process PRC ON PRC.ID=CPO.Process
```

Of course this may have performance implications.